# Laravel Passport Token Expire Methods Not Working

Tags: php, laravel, access-token, laravel-passport

I use passport to make authentication for my API's
i run this command to install passport :

```
php artisan passport:install --force
```

and use the following codes to generate token :

```
$objToken = $user->createToken('Token');
$strToken = $objToken->accessToken;
$expiration = $objToken->token->expires_at->diffForHumans();

return response()->json([
     token' => $strToken,
     'ExpireTime' => $expiration,
], 200);
```

i found that my token lifetime is one year, i just want to make the expire_at column to 1 hour
i read official document and add following codes to AuthServiceProvider:

```
Passport::tokensExpireIn(now()->addDays(15));
Passport::refreshTokensExpireIn(now()->addDays(30));
```

but those codes not working and when i log the expire_at , this still be one year
please help me to change expiration time of my tokens.
thakns alot :)

Comment: maybe the token you are testing with was generated has a lifetime of 1 year. try creating a new token

Comment: every time i register new user and get new one, the life time is one year , i dont know what should i do :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are trying to create **Personal Access Token**.

```php
// Passport::tokensExpireIn(now()->addDays(15));
// Passport::refreshTokensExpireIn(now()->addDays(30));


# Get or set when personal access tokens expire.
Passport::personalAccessTokensExpireIn(now()->addHour(1));
```

Result :

```sh
array:2 [
  "token" => "eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGciOiJSUzI1NiJ9...."
  "ExpireTime" => "59 minutes from now"
]
```

---

#### Update

For Laravel `< v5.7`

> Personal access tokens are always long-lived. Their lifetime is not modified when using the `tokensExpireIn` or `refreshTokensExpireIn` methods.

Comment: This method cannot find in Laravel Passport , Why ?

Comment: What's your Laravel version?

Comment: I Think my version is 5.5

Comment: I used tokensExpireIn  but when i get my token the expire time still is one year

Comment: what should i do now?

Comment: You need to upgrade your Laravel. Better Laravel `6.x`

Comment: can i handle it in laravel 5.5?

Comment: `TokensExpireIn` 'only' works for Authorization Code and Password Grant tokens, not for personal access tokens. If you are good for Laravel, you can try [this one](https://github.com/laravel/passport/issues/162#issuecomment-319157793)

Answer (score 0):

```
$objToken = $user->createToken('Token');
$strToken = $objToken->accessToken;
$expiration = $objToken->token;
$expiration->expires_at = Carbon::now()->addWeeks(1);//example 1 week

$expiration->save();
```

and in AuthServiceProvider.php:

```
public function boot()
{
    $this->registerPolicies();
    Passport::routes();
    Passport::personalAccessTokensExpireIn(Carbon::now()->addDays(2));//example 2 Days
    //
}
```